# Outputting number data into a .txt file in Java

Tags: java, input, output, text-files

For the programming assignment I have is to read data from a file, calculate the average, running total, and list out the original numbers. What I am having trouble with is outputting the data into the output file. I cannot figure out how to print what prints on the console to the output file. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

  // Declare variables
    // Define your file names 
    final String INPUT_FILE  = ("Input.txt");
    final String OUTPUT_FILE = ("Output.txt");

  int numberOfNumbers = 0;   // Number of numbers in the input file
  double sum = 0;            // The sum of the numbers
  double average = 0;        // The average of the numbers read
  double oneNumber;          // An individual number read from the file
  double runningTotal = 0;   // the running total sum of the numbers


  // Access the input/output files
    File inputDataFile = new File(INPUT_FILE);
    Scanner inputFile  = new Scanner(inputDataFile);
    FileWriter outputDataFile = new FileWriter(OUTPUT_FILE);
    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(outputDataFile);
    System.out.println("Reading  file " + INPUT_FILE + "\r\n" +
                       "Creating file " + OUTPUT_FILE);

    // Read the input file and sum the numbers. 

    while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            numberOfNumbers++;
            oneNumber = inputFile.nextDouble();
            sum += oneNumber;                 // Calculate total sum 
            runningTotal += oneNumber;        // Calculate running total
            average = sum / numberOfNumbers;  // Calculate the average

        System.out.printf("%-10.2f\t %.2f\n", oneNumber, runningTotal);

            // 2. write the number and running total to the output file

        }  // End while

    // Add code here to:
    // 1. write the number of numbers, the sum and the average
  //    to the output file using DecimalFormat to format the sum and average
    inputFile.close();  // close the input file
    outputFile.close(); // close the output file

    System.out.println("The sum of the " + numberOfNumbers + 
                             " numbers is " + sum + "\n" +
                     " and the average is " + average);

    System.exit(0); 
  } // End main
} // End class
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("the-file-name.txt", "UTF-8");
writer.println("The first line");
writer.println("The second line");
writer.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

the PrintWriter class that you have already created works just like the System.out console output. If you want to write a line to a file, use

```
outputFile.println("text");
```

If you don't want the newline character to be added to the file after your text, then use

```
outputFile.print("text");
```

it even has a printf function. Here's the documentation [enter link description here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)

Answer (score 0):

In while loop before `printf` use

```
outputFile.printf("%-10.2f\t %.2f\n", oneNumber, runningTotal);
```

And before `System.exit(0)` use

```
    outputFile.println("The sum of the " + numberOfNumbers + " numbers is "
            + sum + "\n" + " and the average is " + average);
    System.out.println("The sum of the " + numberOfNumbers + " numbers is "
            + sum + "\n" + " and the average is " + average);


    inputFile.close(); // close the input file
    outputFile.close(); // close the output file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File("output path");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);


            bw.write(content);//This is the only thing that goes in the while loop!

            bw.close();//do this at the end! of your program.
```

P.S. try googling this stuff before you resort to forums. You'll learn a lot more that way. :)

Happy Coding

Comment: Yeah, i didn't see anything that was really helping me when i googled it, thats why i came here.  And I tried everything except for the printf().  As you can probably tell, i'm extremely new to coding haha